# Google Vr - Unable to load texture

Tags: javascript, google-vr

Good morning, i downloaded the google vr script to try to embed in a webpage a 360 image.
I wanted to try it but the examples and the index.html page does not work and i get those error messages after the script loading:

page: index.html:

Error: Unable to load scene: Required parameter setting.

page: examples/pano/index.html anks

Error: Render: unable to load texture from examples/pano/andes_512.jpg

Does someone know how to solve that issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to host the vr view script on a web server for it to work right. I used XAMPP and it worked fine. Google recommends using a chrome based server though. For more information see: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vr_view_101/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0